# Concatenate distinct values in a group by

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have data like this:

```
Group   Provider
A       ABC
A       DEF
B       DEF
B       HIJ
```

And I want to transform the data like this:

```
Group ProviderList
A      ABC, DEF
B      DEF, HIJ
```

I was trying something like this using a `concat(select distinct...)` but not sure if this is the best approach

```
SELECT distinct
  group, 
  CONCAT(select distinct provider from data)
FROM data 
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: Use `string_agg`.

Comment: No need to do SELECT DISTINCT, your GROUP BY returns no duplicates.

Comment: if you write an answer out i can understand better and maybe mark as best answer @LaurenzAlbe

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What Laurenz meant with string_agg() is the following

```
SELECT
  group, 
  STRING_AGG(Provider,',') as ProviderList
FROM data 
GROUP BY 1
```

Optionally you could also use:

```
STRING_AGG(provider,',' order by Provider)
```

Comment: thank you for the answer! i figured it out prior but this works perfectly